# How to pass variables as arguments only if it is not null in Java

Tags: java, parameter-passing

I have the following code stub where I'm reading a set of values from properties file.
I need to use these values to pass it as arguments to a function only if they aren't NULL.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String arg1 = "arg1";
    String arg2 = "arg2";
    String arg3 = null;
    String arg4 = "arg4";
    .
    .
    .

    testMethod(arg1, arg2, arg3);
}

public void testMethod(String... values) {

}
```

In the above code snippet. I want to call testMethod() with arguments arg1, arg2, arg4 only because arg3 is NULL.

The number of arguments may vary. It will not be 4 all the time.

My code should dynamically check if an argument is not NULL and pass it to the testMethod().

Can I achieve this in Java. If Yes, can someone help me ..

Comment: what you could do is call the `testMethod(String... values)` method by passing an array of all your variables, and in that method you kind of manually check if the variables are `null` and which other method you want to call.

Answer (score 7):

Yeah, there are multiple methods to do this, since the `...` syntax is basically short for passing an array of parameters. So, one way to do this would be for example:

`testMethod(Arrays.stream(args).filter(Objects::nonNull).toArray(String[]::new))`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a list and fill it with the Strings that are not null, and then pass the list if it is not empty.

Answer (score 2):

You should make a `String` list containing all the arguments, iterate over it to check for `null` and then pass the list to `testMethod()`.

Here's a snippet of what I mean:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // This is only a simple example, you can make it way more efficient depending on your parameters
    List<String> arguments = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("arg1", "arg2", null, "arg4", null, "arg5"));
    // This is what actually removes the "null" values
    arguments.removeAll(Collections.singletonList(null));
    // Then you can call your method
    testMethod(arguments);
}
```